# Proving orthogonality of a family of polynomials with respect to inner product

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

there's a question that i've been stuck on and would really like some help with.

Consider a space of polynomials defined on the real line with the following inner product 
$$ \langle p,q\rangle = \int_{\mathbb R} p(x)e^{-x^2/2}q(x) dx $$
where p(x) and q(x) are polynomials.

Consider a family of polynomials defined recursively over $\mathbb R$
$$H_0(x) = 1$$
$$H_1(x) = x$$
$$H_{n+1}(x)=xH_n(x) - H'_n (x) $$

So the question asks us to show that these polynomials form an orthogonal family with respect to the inner product that was previously defined.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the integral evaluated over the real line? Have you tried to show that $H_0 \bot H_1$?

Comment: yes i can show that H_0 is orthogonal to H_1 but i dont think thats sufficient proof?

Comment: If you assume that $H_0,..,H_n$ are orthogonal, can you show that $H_{n+1} $ is orthogonal to  $H_0,..,H_n$?

Comment: Perhaps it might help to note that if $\phi(x) = e^{-{x^2 \over 2}} H_n(x)$ then $\phi'(x) = e^{-{x^2 \over 2}} (H_n'(x) - x H_n(x))$?

Comment: Also note that $H_0,...,H_n$ span the same space as $x \mapsto x^k$ for $k=0,...,n$.

Comment: i understand the logic but i'm not exactly sure how the derivative helps in this case? :/

Comment: Used integration by parts and note that $H_n'$ lies in the span of $H_0,...H_{n-1}$.

Comment: so we are integrating $$int/H_n(x)e^{-x^2/2}H_{n+1}(x)$$, is that correct? to prove orthogonality

Comment: Well, that and more. You want to show that $H_0,...,H_n$ are orthogonal to $H_{n+1}$.

Comment: I do think it involves induction and iterated integration by parts, especially because $e^{-x^2/2}$ dominates any polynomial and flattens the result to $0$ near the 'endpoints'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use induction, but first we make some observations.

First, observe that for $\phi(x)=-e^{-x^2/2}\,f(x)$, it holds that $\phi'(x)=e^{-x^2/2}\,\big(xf(x)-f'(x)\big)$.
In particular, with $\phi_n(x)=e^{-x^2/2}H_n(x)$ we have $\phi_n'(x)=-\phi_{n+1}(x)$.

Secondly, it is a straightforward exercise to check that $H_n$ is a monic $n$-degree polynomial for all $n$.

Finally, it is a common exercise to show that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}e^{-x^2/2}\,p(x)=0$ whenever $p$ is a polynomial.

---

Now, onto the induction. The base case uses $p=H_0$ and $q=H_1$, which should be easy enough to check.

For the induction step, suppose that for all $j \in \{1,\dots,n\}$ and all $i$ with $0\leq i < j$ we have $\langle H_i,H_j\rangle = 0$.
We will show the same holds true when $j=n+1$.
We have:

\begin{align}
\langle H_i,H_{n+1}\rangle=\int\,H_i\,H_{n+1}\,e^{-x^2/2}\,dx
&= \int\,H_i\,\phi_{n+1}(x)\,dx\\
&= \int\,H_i\,\Big(-\phi_n'(x)\Big)\,dx\tag{1}\\
&= \Big[H_i\,\big(-\phi_n\big)\Big]-\int\,H_i'\,\Big(-\phi_n(x)\Big)\,dx\tag{2}\\
&= \underbrace{\Big[-H_i\phi_n\Big]}_{(*)}+\int\,H_i'\,\phi_n(x)\,dx\\
\end{align}

In $(1)$ we used our first observation.
In $(2)$ we used integration by parts.
The boundary component $(*)$ is $0$ as per our third observation above.

In other words, we have

$$\int\,H_i\phi_{n+1}(x)\,dx=\int\,H_i'\,\phi_n(x)\,dx$$

We can repeat the process, at each step differentiating $H_i$ one additional time and reducing the index of $\phi_k$ by $1$.
Since $i<n+1$ as per our induction hypothesis, in $i$ steps the $H_i$ factor of the ingrand will be reduced to the constant $i!$ (here, we have used our second observation) and the index on what remains of $phi_k$ will be positive.
At this point, the integral will have been reduced to

$$i!\int\,\phi_{n+1-i}(x)\,dx= i!\int\, H_{n+1-i}(x)\,e^{-x^2/2}\,dx=i!\,\langle H_{n+1-i},H_0\rangle,$$

which is $0$ as per our induction hypothesis.

> You may notice the argument above doesn't quite work when $i=0$...
>   In this case, however, the problem would have been solved earlier, in equation $(1)$: here we could apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and our third observation to conclude that the integral vanishes.

Comment: wow, thank you so much for that clearly articulated response. I understand it perfectly now! :))